# How to get all attributes with the same name?

Tags: c#, html, attributes, nodes

let's say this is the xml file

```
<div Pictures>
<span Pic1>
  <a title="pic1" class="thumb" image="LinkToImage.com">
  </a>
</span >
<span Pic2>
  <a title="pic2" class="thumb-small" image="LinkToImage2.com">
  </a>
</span >
</div >
```

How do I get all image attributes from this page? I know I need to use the XPath syntax //@image but I can't find the code to collect all these attributes and put them in a foreach. I've tried something like this but that didn't work

```
var WebgetME_ = new HtmlWeb();
var docME_ = WebgetME_.Load(MEURL_);
foreach (HtmlAttribute HA_ME in docME_.DocumentNode.Attributes["//@image"])) { ;}
```

How do you get all attribute info with the same attribute name from a page?

Comment: This is tagged as `XML` and is crearly `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get all image attributes from this page?

I believe you can do the following:

```
var images =
    from link in docME_.Descendants("a")
    where link.Attributes.Contains("image")
    select link.Attributes["image"].Value;
```

This

- gets all `<a .../>` nodes
- filters them by having an an "image" attribute
- retrieves the value for this attribute.

Comment: And then I just do `foreach(string linktoimage in images)` or what is the best way to use all values?

Comment: @Strinix you can either do `foreach` if you want to iterate over them, or do  `images.ToList()` or `images.ToArray()` if you want to use them as a list or an array.

Comment: Is there any difference in using images.ToArray() first and then using foreach on the array or just going for the foreach right ahead? I do not need the images after I've done what I had to do in the foreach so it's a one time use. @Alex

Comment: If you only need to iterate over them and you don't need them after iterating just do `foreach`, no need to allocate a list or array in that case.